# How to find TableRow in a flutter test

Tags: flutter

I am having issues with finding table rows when testing using Flutter. It is able to find the table, and when printing the tableWidget, it does show that the table has contents, with the keys that I am searching for, thus I am confused as to why the tester is not able to find them.

```
await buildApp(tester);
await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1));
var table = find.byKey(const Key('Tablebase'));
expect(table, findsOneWidget);

var tableWidget = table.evaluate().single.widget as Table;
print(tableWidget.children);

expect(find.byType(TableRow), findsOneWidget);
expect(find.byKey(const ValueKey('row-0')), findsOneWidget);
```

The print statement gives the following (trimmed down to remove containers): 
[TableRow([<'row-0'>],

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `TableRow` is not a widget so you can't do `find.byType(TableRow)`.

However, you managed to get a reference to your Table already, so you can do something like:

```dart
expect(tableWidget.children.first.key, const ValueKey('row-0'))
```